# How to set Prolog Interpreter path in Eclipse which is being used in Windows?

Tags: database, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, prolog

I have downloaded the tool for Prolog Interpreter plugin for Eclipse. But I am not able to set the path for interpreter. I am getting the following error

```
Problems executing prolog interpreter.
Prolog interpreter path may be incorrect! Check the 'Prolog Preferences'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\br.usp.ime.prolog_1.0.0\prolog": 
CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

These are the contents I have in the downloded Prolog zip:

Editor (folder)

Icons (foler)

'plugin.xml'

prolog.jar

prologsrc.zip

I have tried to set the path pointing the jar but it is still not working. Could anyone please help me regarding this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must set the path to the *Prolog* interpreter.
Try downloading Ciao Prolog, installing it, and then fix your 'Prolog Preferences'.